# process 'forkPoolworker-5' pid:111 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'

Tags: django, celery

hello every one who helps me?
python:3.8

```
Django==4.0.4
celery==5.2.1
```

I am using python/Django/celery to do something,when I get data from hive by sql,my celely worker get this error "process 'forkPoolworker-5'  pid:111 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'",and then,my task is not be used to finish and the tcp connect is closing! what can I do for it to solve?

I try to do:

```
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1  # 单work最多任务使用数
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 3  # 单worker最大并发数
CELERYD_MAX_MEMORY_PER_CHILD = 1024*1024*2  # 单任务可占用2G内存
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3

-Ofair
```

but these is not using for solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIGKILL is raised by system, most likely due to memory or storage, monitor how much memory a celery task takes by running `-P solo` option or `-c 1` and allocate sufficient memory accordingly.

To check memory usage either use `pmap <pid>` or `ps -a -o rss,vsz`. Please search rss and vsz for more details (in short `rss` is RAM and `vsz` is virtual memory).

`CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1` kills process after every task, so `CELERYD_MAX_MEMORY_PER_CHILD` has no affect ie worker waits for completion of task before enforcing limit on running child process.

Comment: i think you are right this error is due to memory but i found it is not full use of the CPU and kernels,my machine is 8c 16G,how can i do for using full of my resource?

Comment: It depends on case by case, to utilise max resource you need to understand the  kind of task you are running.

Comment: Judging by what you have posted, you seem to be getting data from hive (very large amount of data probably). You'll need to recheck the code
1. Divide your huge task into smaller tasks. 
2. If you can't do the first then try fetching records in an iterator (more like "yield row") or batches of some 100 rows, it will reduce your memory footprint.

Comment: thanks.I try to change the code and add the memory to solve it.
until now, I still want to know how can I retry it auto.

Comment: As a general rule if the process is getting killed because of some issue, so you need to solve the issue (seems to be memory in your case). You can do that by adding resources (to some extent) or reduce footprint in code. If you don't solve the issue it doesn't matter how many times you retry, the issue will resurface.