# AWS MWAA Airflow task fails with no log and nonsensical duration

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I have an MWAA Environment running at AWS.  Log levels are all on "ERROR" for Tasks, WebServer, Worker, Scheduler and Dag Processor.
At random times, tasks just fail for no reason and no visible logs.  We can then see the attached picture showing an immensely long duration, but in reality it only runs a few seconds or minutes, also reflected in the start time (in Run ID) and end time.  Set timeout is btw 2 hours.

[image: Failed task information with awkwardly long duration time.]

What I've tried:  Since some of the DAGs do contain a bunch of tasks, I've tried to make them as little concurrent as possible and schedule accordingly.  Other people had identified this as a potential error source.  It is mainly the DAGs with many tasks that fail like this.

There are no task errors, but I can find
`[WARNING] Worker with pid 13924 was terminated due to signal 15`
in the WebServer logs, and

```
[2023-11-02 10:16:30,563: ERROR/MainProcess] Timed out waiting for UP message from <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-44, started daemon)>
[2023-11-02 10:16:30,591: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-44' pid:1492 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
```

The timestamps of these log entries do not clearly correspond to each other, and neither clearly to the failed DAG/task, but occur roughly within the same hour.

Does anyone know what this problem could be, how it can be amended, and especially how the immensely long duration note can come about?  I do not wish to increase the instance size on AWS due to cost reasons.  I appreciate any hints.

We have about 40 DAGs which run at least daily, some more often.  The DAG runs themselves, when they don't fail, are no longer than a few minutes (< 10 mins).

We are running Airflow 2.4.3 with a `mw1.small` and 2 scheduler counts configuration

Comment: Same issue here. Running on MWAA Airflow 2.2.2, which version of Airflow are you using?

Comment: Good point, we are running Airflow 2.4.3 with a `mw1.small` and 2 scheduler counts configuration.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I also get tasks which eventually pass but have multiple retries, the initial tries don't have logs (going to the logs in the web console just gives `Could not read remote logs from log_group`. If I look at the gantt the vast majority of my timeline has no active task. A job which runs locally in under a minute takes 20+ minutes in Airflow. MWAA Airflow 2.4.3 `mw1.small`. I'm trying to add more workers, but so far no solution.

Comment: Looking into the worker logs I'm getting the same issue with `exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'`. From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74682543/process-forkpoolworker-5-pid111-exited-with-signal-9-sigkill) it seems like the system is likely killing the celery process due to lack of resources. That's likely why it doesn't write logs and the time outs are resulting in the long run times.

Comment: Sounds like exactly the same issue.  I have significantly reduced the number of tasks in our dags, squeezing a bunch of tasks into a single custom operator.  I will now wait over the weekend and see if the number of these errors drops significantly...

Answer (score 1):

Do you think you're running out of memory on the worker node? I've run into this issue when trying to hold too much data in memory in the past, check the [cluster metrics in cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-container-database-and-queue-utilization-metrics-for-the-amazon-mwaa-environment/). For me I found the issue by looking at `Maximum` statistic the BaseWorker MemoryUtilization metric with `Period` of 1 minute.

The workers in the `mw1.small` class have 2GB of memory and 10GB of disk. As far as I know there's not a way to check the disk space usage in metrics, but I think that could cause a `SIGKILL` of the worker as well.

If you find there's an issue with running out of memory or disk it's probably because you're trying to do more compute in Airflow than it's designed for; maybe try to offload some of the compute to a data warehouse or other AWS service triggered by Airflow like EMR? Make sure you're streaming data to S3 rather than caching locally?

Sorry, I don't have an explanation for the weird duration metric. Have you looked at the gantt to see if there's an issue with the end timestamp maybe?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the CloudWatch metrics, I somehow did not look close enough earlier.  The scheduler regularly scratches the 100% CPU utilisation and is never below 90% CPU.  All other parts are very well within their limits, so I think the scheduler is the key point here (not computational load in the tasks).  I am still reducing the task number and have the feeling this is reducing the amount of this errors.

Comment: FYI @AdagioMolto, I think I figured out what my issue was, I was having tasks timeout on the DagBag import. Apparently that can be an issue if your DAGs are really complex. I also saw CPU reach 100%, but that ended up being a red herring in my case. I changed `core.dagbag_import_timeout=120` and it seems like my issue is resolved. The error message was hard to find in the worker stream but it contained `airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: DagBag import timeout for /usr/local/airflow/dags/...`.